# How to echo query results from Parse.com in table form? Parse PHP SDK

Tags: php, html, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve this class from Parse.com and show it in a table form in a php website. It will be very helpful if someone can show me an example of how it's done. With little html and php knowledge, everything has been so confusing.

```
     <?php
     include('parsekey.php');

     use Parse\ParseQuery;

     try{
       $query = new ParseQuery("Stock");
       $query->select("Stock");
       $results = $query->find();

       echo "RESULT: ";

       print_r($results);
       echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " data.";
        } 
     catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.... just loop them.

```
 try{
   $query = new ParseQuery("Stock");
   $query->select("Stock");
   $results = $query->find();

   foreach($results as $result){$column_value = $result->get('column_name');}
   echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " data.";
    } 
 catch (Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
 }

 ?>
```